# Semi-reflexive dual

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I am looking for an example of a semi-reflexive locally convex topological vector space, whose strong dual is not semi-reflexive. Is there some well-known example ?

Answer (score 4):

The standard example is the dual of a non reflexive Banach space under the Mackey topology from its predual.  See e.g. Porblem 20.A of Kelley & Namioka's "Linear Topological Spaces".  This book has a pretty good discussion of semi-reflexivity.

Comment: Whether you take the Mackey or the weak*-topology does not really matter. So, this is essentially the same example as in my answer.

Comment: Right, Jochen; I should have noted that. I wanted to give a book reference.

Answer (score 3):

I think that semi-reflexivity means that the space equals its bidual algebraically (but not necessarily topologically).

Take a non-reflexive Banach space $X$ (like $X=c_0$) and endow the dual $Y=X'$ with the weak* topology. Then $Y'=X$ so that $Y''=Y$ but the strong dual $X$ is not reflexive.

Comment: I meant $Y$ to be the counterexample.